# Check if coordinates are valid EPSG 3857 , using Openlayers 5

Tags: openlayers, map-projections, openlayers-5

I am using openlayers 5 along with angular6.

I have created a simple form that user can give a X and Y of EPSG3857 coordinates, submit and a point will be rendered there and the map will zoom there. I am using a vector layer for that.

I want to check if the XY are valid EPSG3857 coordinates somehow.

I tried using a `try/catch` block, but this works the second time I submit the form.

I put some crazy XY like `6.34  2401111118651.91`, I submit, the point is created and the map zooms in nowhere, in a white background. I have to submit the same form a second time, for the `try/catch` to actually catch the error.

How can I fix that and check the coords right away? This is the code I wrote

```
  coordsSubmitted(){
    let point = [this.coordsForm.controls.coordsx.value, this.coordsForm.controls.coordsy.value];          
    try {
      this.coordFeature.setGeometry(new Point(point));  
      this.coordsource.addFeatures([this.coordFeature]) ;  
      this.olmap.getView().animate({
        center: point,
        duration: 2500,
        zoom:10
      });     
    } catch (error) {
      this.coordsFormErrorMsg = 'Error. Only EPSG 3857 coords.';
    }       
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check that your inputs are within the projection bounds. The acceptable values for this [projection](https://epsg.io/3857) are:

Min X: -20026376.39
Min Y: -20048966.10
Max X: 20026376.39
Max Y: 20048966.10

You could restrict these limits to the area you are mapping.